# Parse PFQueryTableViewController shows empty UITableViewCells in black

Tags: ios, uitableview, pfquery

I cannot figure out why the empty tableview cells are black as seen in the image below? I am using Parse, and the PFQueryTableView is working properly, but the empty cells always appear black. Does anyone know why this is happening?

[image: Why are the empty UITableViewCells black?]

Comment: Your table view shouldn't have `clearColor` as it's background colour. There's no view behind the table view, so there's no colour to display. Black is the absence of colour.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have it set as white though?

Comment: Are you sure? Check again, that's the only possibility. Do you have any views behind your table view?

Comment: I triple checked. I went to IB, clicked on the tableview, and its background color is set to white. There are no views behind it unfortunately.

Comment: Are your cells white too? Are you sure you aren't setting colours anywhere in code?

Comment: I am using custom cells, and there background color is also set to white. I do not set any colors in my code.

Comment: Log out your table view at run time and see if the colours are proper at runtime.

Comment: Okay so when I set the color programmatically in ViewDidLoad it works. You were right, it was the color. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Post what you did as an answer and accept it to help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I ended up having to programmatically set the UITableView background color to white in the ViewDidLoad method:

```
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

The tableview and its cells were clear and therefore appeared black as a result.